# K-means Clustering 3D points in space using C#

Tags: c#, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am looking for a package that has implemented K-means clustering algorithm in C# (For 3D points). I have been looking around but not sure about some of the implementations. Do you have any suggestion or used any of them?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I recall correctly it isn't a difficult algorithm to implement yourself... might be worth doing

Comment: I have been searching for "k-means clustering 3d points c#"

Comment: yes. If I don't find anything I will code it myself. Because of a deadline I preferred to use an existing one if available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) does K-means. There is the excellent .NET port [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/).

Comment: Yes. I ended up using this and it is exactly what I needed. thank you.